# toggle the visibility of a div in jquery when the preceeding div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to build a simple webpage with questions and answers, and the structure looks something like this:

```
<div class="Q">Question goes here</div>
<div class="A">Answer goes here</div>

<div class="Q">Question goes here</div>
<div class="A">Answer goes here</div>

<div class="Q">Question goes here</div>
<div class="A">Answer goes here</div>

<div class="Q">Question goes here</div>
<div class="A">Answer goes here</div>

etc
```

When the page loads, the answers are hidden (easily done in CSS).
I want to be able to click on any given question, and display the answer to that question, and only the answer to that question. On the other hand, I would prefer not to use ids for now. 
Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Here's what I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Q').click(function(e) {
      function toggle() {
        $(".Q").next().toggle();
      }
    });
});
```

How should I go about it? Preferably in simple terms, since my programming skills are very much at the beginner level. If anybody knows of any examples doing something similar, that would be great (all I can find are examples that use ids, or examples that work on all similar elements...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it with jQuery. You need to group each pair into a parent div and call pass that div to a function when it's clicked. And then, we can find the answer inside that specific child and show it. Your code should look like:

HTML for questions and answers. You can add as many as you want.

```
<div onclick="showAns($(this))">
    <div class="Q">Question 1</div>
    <div class="A">Answer 1</div>
</div>
<div onclick="showAns($(this))">
    <div class="Q">Question 2</div>
    <div class="A">Answer 2</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/Jquery:

```
<script>
    function showAns(v){
        v.find(".A").css('display','block');
    }
</script>
```

CSS to hide the answers at the beginning:

```
<style>
    .A{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Ajith, thank you so much!!! I ended up using "v.find(".A").toggle();" to toggle it, but it was EXACTLY was I was looking for.